# index on oracle 11g question

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ora-00904

i have table (MEN) with 900,000 records.

in this table i have field `IP` and `Tdate`.

when i run query:

```
select * from MEN where IP = '1.1.1.1' and Tdate = TO_DATE('07/04/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

it takes long time until i get Result.

i try to make index like this:

```
create index
    my_in
on
   MEN (IP,Tdate );
```

but how to run the query to get fast Result?

i try this:

```
select My_in from MEN where IP = '1.1.1.1' and Tdate = TO_DATE('07/04/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

and get error: `ORA-00904`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not use the index name (My_in) in the select. The database itself will figure out to use the index. So you should just do the same select as in your first example.

Comment: OK, and if i have one more index for example create index
    my_in2 on MEN (IP ); how the oracle will know what index to use ?

Comment: It will pick the one it thinks is best. It determines this by looking at the statistics for the table, which is why you sometimes have to update statistics for a table/index in order to have it use the right index.

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid SQL. `My_in` is the name of your index.

Try again with:

```
select * 
  from MEN
 where IP = '1.1.1.1' 
   and Tdate = TO_DATE('07/04/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Alternatively, if you want to know if the server will use a plan using your newly created index, you can inspect the output of the `explain` command:

```
explain plan for
select * 
  from MEN
 where IP = '1.1.1.1' 
   and Tdate = TO_DATE('07/04/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Take a look at Oracle's documentation on [EXPLAIN PLAN](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm). It will help you with this and many other SQL optimizations.

Comment: +1 for the drawing attention to `explain plan`, however it should be `explain plan for select * from MEN...`, followed by `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display())` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

in your query

```
select My_in from MEN where IP = '1.1.1.1' and Tdate = TO_DATE('07/04/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

the my_in is the index name. If you want to force the index usage, then you can hint your query

```
  select /*+INDEX(My_in MEN) */  * from MEN where IP = '1.1.1.1' and Tdate = TO_DATE('07/04/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: +1 but most of the time the hint is not required (and can even cause a query to run slower) and should be avoided.